# Subclasses as arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, function, arguments, subclass

I am attempting to create something like this:

```
class food
{
public:
   void EAT(); //Whatever happens...
   int bitesLeft //This is decreased by one each time you eat the food
};

class cheese: public food
{
public:
   void EAT(); //Some overloaded form of the "eat" command... 
};
```

Is there a way to create one of each at runtime, and have a function that can take either one as arguments without screwing up the bitesLeft variable of each one?

Comment: The `EAT` method in the parent class isn't overloaded, that refers to functions with the same name but different arguments. You're thinking of _overriding_, which occurs when a derived class implements a function of the same name and arguments as in a parent class. But in this case it's not being overridden either, since the one in the parent class isn't marked `virtual`. What's happening is that the definition in the derived class is _hiding_ the one in the parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
void myfunc(food* f)
{
    f->EAT();
}

int main()
{
    food f;
    cheese c;
    myfunc(&f);
    myfunc(&c);
    return 0;
}
```

However, for this to work, you need to declare EAT() as virtual in the food class, as in `virtual void EAT();`. Also, you probably want to declare bitesLeft as protected, so that only the class itself as well as the subclasses can access it.

Comment: Thanks!  that took care of my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want something like:

```
function doStuff(food * f) {
    f->EAT();
}
```

And you want this to call the specialised `EAT` if a cheese is passed in, or the non-specialised form if a `food` is passed in. In this case, you need a *virtual* function:

```
class food {
  public:
    virtual void EAT();
    virtual ~food(); // Any class being used polymorphically should have
                     // a virtual destructor
}

class cheese : public food {
  public:
    virtual void EAT();
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'without screwing up the `bytesLeft` variable. This is a public data member, so it's possible for any code to modify the value of the variable in ways you weren't expecting. This includes code in the `cheese` class, but also code that's not in either of the classes.

If you want to prevent code in the `cheese.EAT` method from modifying the `bitesLeft` member then you should declare it as `private` in the base class.

Comment: also add virtual destructor to food.

Comment: Good point. I wasn't intending this to be a fully working example, but I'll add the virtual destructor in because not having one would be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The member variables of two objects are separate. This code works as you expect:

```
void AFunction( food& x ) {
  x.EAT();
}

food a;
a.bitesLeft = 10;
cheese b;
b.bitesLeft = 5;

AFunction(a);   // a.bitesLeft --> 9
AFunction(b);   // b.bitesLeft --> 4
```

Comment: This will copy the food object, and then call `EAT()` on the copy, which will not modify the original object, as your comment seems to indicate, right?

Comment: @JaredC, You are right. I have added the & operator at the argument. It should be correct now.